# Is win32security.logonuser is secured? Or the inputs sent as plain-text

Tags: security, frontend, backend, pywin32

Im trying to verify if user credentials getting him logged or not.
this input sent from the front-end to the back-end.
I need to find a way to secure the info which sent through all the way (end point computer to the back-end). what is the best way to do it? and is the win32security.logonuser is secured enough (i use it on the back-end).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) is a wrapper over native *Win API*s.

[[ActiveState]: win32security.LogonUser](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32security__LogonUser_meth.html) (this is the closest of an official doc that I could find) is just a wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: LogonUserW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw). Here's what the latter states:

> *lpszPassword* [in, optional]
>           
>   A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the plaintext password for the user account specified by *lpszUsername*. When you have finished using the password, clear the password from memory by calling the [SecureZeroMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877(v=vs.140).aspx) function. For more information about protecting passwords, see [Handling Passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/SecBP/handling-passwords).

If you take a look at the source code: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - (b222) pywin32/win32/src/win32security.i:*1021*](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/b222/win32/src/win32security.i#L1021) (`PyObject *PyLogonUser(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)`), you'll notice that at the end of the function,

- *SecureZeroMemory*
- *PyWinObject_FreeWCHAR*

are called upon sensitive data.
So, all the guidelines are met, there is of course the time window when the password string is in memory (between filling and releasing it, here the *Python* overhead will add a few milli / nanosecs), but this is as secure as you can get using this method.